# In angular datatable how to change show records per page options

Tags: angularjs, datatable

In jquery data table I can change records per page option by

```
"aLengthMenu": [[50, 100, 150, 200, -1],
[50, 100, 150, 200, "All"]],
```

Anyone know how to achieve this in angular?

I tried

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('order', [1, 'asc']).withDisplayLength(250);
```

and

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('order', [1, 'asc']).withOption('LengthMenu', [[50, 100, 150, 200, -1], [50, 100, 150, 200, "All"]])
```

I want to show 50, 100, 150, 200

I searched at http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/api but couldn't found

Comment: Did you find any solution ??

Comment: Got solution here [Here Link](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthMenu) .

Comment: @Usmanlqbal Angular Datatables are different

Answer (score 12):

You were close... use 'lengthMenu' option and only one array:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('order', [1, 'asc']).withOption('lengthMenu', [50, 100, 150, 200])
```

Comment: how to change label of `-1` to `All`

Comment: @usmanlqbal : For -1 to All -> Enclose 2 arrays in 1 -> like this -> .withOption('lengthMenu', [[20, 40, 60, -1], [20, 40, 60, "All"]])

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer!

So there is a variable you use in the datatable called     `$scope.dtOptions`
and there is a way to add on to that with   `.withOption('lengthMenu', [50, 100, 150, 200]);`

Now, technically that changed the length options not the length, but in my case all I need is to set the lowest length option to the length I want, and I effectively changed the default length of the table.

Example:

```
$scope.dtOptions =   DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withDOM('<"html5buttons"B>lTfgitp')
    .withButtons([])
    .withOption('order', [1, 'asc'])
    .withOption('lengthMenu', [50, 100, 150, 200]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withDisplayLength(10) 
// Default page size - 10,25,50,100
```

You can customize your list by using:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('lengthMenu', [10, 25, 50, 100])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple datatable in the project and wants to add LengthMenu as all you can add it in Run block

```
app.run(['DTDefaultOptions',function(DTDefaultOptions) {
    DTDefaultOptions.setOption('lengthMenu',[[10, 20, 25, 50, -1],[10, 20, 25, 50, 'All']]);
}]);
```

If you want to add any option which are supported by Jquery Datatable you can use

```
DTDefaultOptions.setOption(key, value);
```